# Brush print is not consecutive

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to implement the Brushing function to my Paint project.

My idea is everywhen I move and press mouse left button on canvas, I'll add a ellipse to Free-brush (like MSPaint)

Everything was good until I move mouse faster. [image] >> the brush print is separated.

Can anyone explain to me and give me some hints to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
Point _startPoint, _endPoint;
    private void MyCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
                    _startPoint = e.GetPosition(MyCanvas);
                    Ellipse MyBrush_Ellipse = new Ellipse();
                    MyBrushing.CreateBrush(_cl1, _cl2, ref MyBrush_Ellipse, Mybrush_type);

                    Canvas.SetTop(MyBrush_Ellipse, _startPoint.Y);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(MyBrush_Ellipse, _startPoint.X);
    }

    private void MyCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
             _endPoint = e.GetPosition(MyCanvas);
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                        Ellipse MyBrush_Ellipse = new Ellipse();
                        MyBrushing.CreateBrush(_cl1, _cl2, ref MyBrush_Ellipse, Mybrush_type);

                        Canvas.SetTop(MyBrush_Ellipse, _endPoint.Y);
                        Canvas.SetLeft(MyBrush_Ellipse, _endPoint.X);

                        MyCanvas.Children.Add(MyBrush_Ellipse);
                        MyCanvas.CaptureMouse();
                        _myUndoRedo.PushToStackForBrush(MyBrush_Ellipse);
          }
    }

     private void MyCanvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
                 MyCanvas.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }
```

Comment: Is there any change if you move ellipse creation out of `MyCanvas_MouseMove` event similar to `Mybrush_type`?

Comment: Instead of adding individual Ellipses you probably want to add a single Polyline and then on mouse move add a new Point to its `Points` collection.

Comment: I've tried to use Polyline as @Clemens's comment. But the canvas became lag when the Polyline became longer.

Answer (score 1):

The mouse is not moving constantly over the screen. When moving faster from A to B the mouse actually does not neccessarily move over every part of the screen in between.

To solve your problem draw a line instead of drawing an ellipse at the mouse's position. Therefore you have to store the point the mouse has been before. After a movement draw a line from the stored, last known point to the actual point.

Comment: If I draw a line, it just a straight line but the Brush is not a straight line. Because when I brush, I wanna draw everything I want. It's not alwalys straight line.

Comment: I see the point. Afaik there is no possibility to increase the amount of mouse move messages sent. A workaround might be to use splines.